# Is "bingo" a common phrase in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage

Is "bingo" a common phrase in everyday conversation ? Google gemini and ChatGPT  give me different answers.

Gemini says no.

[image: gemini]

ChatGPT says yes

[image: ChatGPT]

Comment: What do you mean by "common in everyday conversation"?  A word most people would understand when they heard it used, or a word that you'd hear at least once a day? Yes to the former, no to the latter.  You could go weeks or months and never hear the exclamatory word **Bingo!**

Comment: What @TimR said. Except I think the question *can't* be salvaged by a precise definition of what "common in everyday conversation" actually means. We can be pretty certain the vast majority of native Anglophones will *understand* exclamatory *"**Bingo**!"*. But I'm sure any attempt to "quantify" the prevalence would just be an Off Topic ***matter of opinion.***

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking us to verify chat-bot output.

Comment: If I wasn't got an answer I would just delete my question to save your trouble. Man, I just asked a question, why makes me feel I commit a crime?! I know using "everyday conversation" is not right, but I just meant was it used frequently.

Comment: _Bingo_ is a word, not a phrase.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a generational thing (ie certain generations of people say it) but yes, "*bingo!*" is still said (and understood) as a declaration of success. It is also often said somewhat sarcastically when someone else belatedly comprehends something that has been painstakingly explained to them.

Note that 'Bingo' is also the *name* of a popular group game of chance involving random numbers being called (like lotto), in which the first person to collect all their numbers and shout "*bingo!*" is the winner. However, the call of "*bingo!*" as a declaration of success developed separately. Before this, the game was known as 'Housey Housey'. Still, many associate the cry with this game, and while it was for a long time considered a game for older generations (in the UK at least) it has had a resurgence of popularity with younger generations with large events incorporating the game with music and lights akin to a dance club atmosphere. So, perhaps the declaration will also resonate with younger people, too.

Comment: My mother used to cry 'House!' when she had a full card.